# Match string without host

Tags: php, regex

I have example here https://regex101.com/r/ZDof07/1

I need to select strings that don't contain http.

So, in my example I need to get string:

```
url ( /global/css/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regularhttp.eot )
url(/global/css/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix)
```

I use this regular expression:

```
/url\s*\((?!http)[^\)]+\)/gmi
```

The expression takes even more the string:

```
url(    http://www.neco.cz/global/css/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix)
```

but I don't want it because it contains a "http"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with corrected lookahead assertion:

```
url\s*\((?![^)]*http:)[^)]+\)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZDof07/2)

Here `(?![^)]*http:)` is a negative lookahead assertion that will fail the match if we have string `http:` ahead of us following 0 or more `non-(` characters.